# Sharepoint custom Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I've a got a code snippet below modified from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx :

```
public class WebPartBla : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
{
    private ArrayList someList;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        someList = new ArrayList();

        SPWeb myWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
        foreach(SPList list in myWeb.Lists)
        {
            if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
            {
                someList(list.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Render this Web Part to the output parameter specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="output"> The HTML writer to write out to </param>
    protected override void RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        string strHTML = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
        {
            strHTML = strHTML + "The task " + someList.Description + "<BR><BR>";
        }
        output.Write(strHTML);
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me with

1. how to use this code as SharePoint Web Part?
2. how to deploy this to the sharepoint as web part?
3. how does the RenderWebPart method above gets used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need visual studio and SharePoint on the same machine to do any development.

Create an empty sharepoint project then add a webpart to the project. Put the code you have there into the webpart code file and build the solution (you will need to specify the URL of your local SP to do this). You can then deploy via the right click menu. An additional component of this build is a WSP file which you can take and deploy to other sharepoint environments.

THe renderWebPart menthod here allows you to directly write HTML for the webpart in code. Another option here is to use a visual web part.

heres a good tutorial (with pictures) showing how to create a webpart
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/15/intro-to-sharepoint-2010-development-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part.aspx

Comment: Thank you, does renderWebPart method gets called by Sharepoint engine or do we need to explicitely call?

Comment: Hi @Luke McGregor, if you could clarify the above query will be great

Comment: Both CreateChildControls and RenderWebPart are called by ASP.Net\SharePoint automatically. Render is called last and outputs the html to be displayed on page.

Comment: FYI.. the steps for deploying using SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2007 are very different. @flybyte, you may want to clarify which version you are using.

Comment: Render webpart is actually called by the webpart framework (which lives outside of sharepoint in most cases) but from your point of view, yes its called by sharepoint, IE when you load a page in SP with a bunch of webparts, render webpart will be called on each one